# Find Factors of a Number and Save to an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program to find perfect numbers. The first step in doing this is to find all of the factors of a number. I need some code to find the factor of a number and save the factors to an array (NOT print the numbers). This is what I have so far, but it returns a NullPointerException:

```
public static int[] getFactors(int number) {
    int factorNumber = 1;
    int varArrayStoreID = 0;
    int[] factors = null;

    while(factorNumber <= number){
        if(number % factorNumber == 0){
            varArrayStoreID = varArrayStoreID + 1;
            factors[varArrayStoreID] = factorNumber;
        }
        factorNumber++;
    }

    return factors;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to initialize  int[] factors = null; to something and not null ...

Comment: Your `int[] factors = null;` explicitly creates your problem.  Where did you get this code from anyway?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have to initialize your `Array` before you can try and add anything to it. This doesn't really work in your case since you do not know how many factors a number will have until you do your looping but we need to know how many there are when initializing the array. I would suggest changing from an `Array` to a `List` so your collection can be dynamic. Something like this:

```
int factorNumber = 1;
List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
while(factorNumber <= number){
    if(number % factorNumber == 0){
        factors.add(factorNumber);
    }
    factorNumber++;
}
```

The final product of this, though, is a `List<Integer`. If you want to return an `Array`, you are going to have to loop through and make an array:

```
int[] output = new int[factors.size()];
for (int i=0; i<factors.size(); i++){
    output[i] = factors.get(i);
}
return output;
```

Or if you don't like my changes and you don't want to use `List` at all you can do something like this to solve your problem:

```
int factorNumber = 1;
int varArrayStoreID = 0;
int[] factors = new int[number];
while(factorNumber <= number){
    if(number % factorNumber == 0){
        varArrayStoreID = varArrayStoreID + 1;
        factors[varArrayStoreID] = factorNumber;
    }
    factorNumber++;
}
return Arrays.copyOfRange(factors, 0, varArrayStoreID);
```